# How to add li class to MegaMenu from marioloncarek?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I add a class to the first

element in the megamenu  container (see screenshot) without adding it to the normal  container?

link: https://github.com/marioloncarek/megamenu-js

[image: megamenu js]

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Maybe you can clarify what you actually want to achieve and how your current HTML/jQuery code looks? Or is the HTML not controllable by you and you want to modify it via jQuery?

Comment: I try using it with Joomla CMS and want the class to be added automatically - so I thought to modify/add it with jQuery. But the properties of the normal-sub and the megamenu - sub are the same. So if I add a class via jQuery both are affected.

Comment: You can target a specific element in a collection. If you know that the megamenu sub is always the second one or the last one etc, you can specifically target that.